# query becomes slow with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, group-by

I have spent 4 hours googling and trying all sorts of indexes, mysqlyog, reading, searching etc.  When I add the GROUP BY the query changes from 0.002 seconds to 0.093 seconds.  Is this normal and acceptable?  Or can I alter the indexes and/or the query?

Table:

```
uniqueid    int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment  
ip  varchar(64) YES     NULL        
lang    varchar(16) YES MUL NULL        
timestamp   int(11) YES MUL NULL        
correct decimal(12,2)   YES     NULL        
user    varchar(32) YES     NULL        
timestart   int(11) YES     NULL        
timeend int(11) YES     NULL        
speaker varchar(64) YES     NULL        
postedAnswer    int(32) YES     NULL        
correctAnswerINT    int(32) YES     NULL
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  SQL_NO_CACHE 
  user,
  lang,
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  SUM(correct) AS correct,
  ROUND(SUM(correct) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS score,
  TIMESTAMP
FROM
  maths_score
WHERE TIMESTAMP > 1
  AND lang = 'es'
GROUP BY USER
ORDER BY (
    (SUM(correct) / COUNT(*) * 100) + SUM(correct)
  ) DESC
LIMIT 500
```

explain extended:

```
    id  select_type  table        type    possible_keys              key             key_len  ref       rows  filtered  Extra                                                                
------  -----------  -----------  ------  -------------------------  --------------  -------  ------  ------  --------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
     1  SIMPLE       maths_score  ref     scoretable,fulltablething  fulltablething  51       const    10631    100.00  Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Current indexes (I have tried many)

```
Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment

uniqueid    BTREE   Yes No  uniqueid    21262   A   No  

scoretable  BTREE   No  No  timestamp   21262   A   Yes 
    lang    21262   A   Yes

fulltablething  BTREE   No  No  lang    56  A   Yes 
    timestamp   21262   A   Yes
    user    21262   A   Yes
```

Comment: It's important to understand that your 'order by' clause requires mysql to sort all of the output prior to emitting anything because this clause contains computed values.

Comment: To improve the performance of the same queue you need to create 3 indexes. (I think current indexing is incorrect). 1- Index1 on TIMESTAMP + lang 2- index2 on USER and 3- index3 on correct. Note: Sequence of the columns in index matter.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Do you have `INDEX(lang, TIMESTAMP)`?  ([*Why.*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql))  It is likely to help both versions of the query.

Without the `GROUP BY`, you get one row, correct?  With the `GROUP BY`, you get many rows, correct?  Guess what, it takes more time to deliver more rows.

In addition, the `GROUP BY` *probably* involves an extra sort.  The `ORDER BY` involves a sort, but in one case there is only 1 row to sort, hence faster.  If there are a million `USERs`, then the `ORDER BY` will need to sort a million rows, only to deliver 500.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each case -- you will see *some* of what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

So you ran the query without `GROUP BY` and got one result row in 0.002 secs. Then you added `GROUP BY` (and `ORDER BY` obviously) and ended up with multiple result rows in 0.093 secs.

In order to produce this result, the DBMS must somehow order your records by user or create buckets per user, so as to get record count, sum, etc. per user. This takes of course much more time than just running through the table, counting records and summing up a value unconditionally. At last the DBMS must even sort these results again. I am not surprised this runs much longer.

The most appropriate index for this query should be:

```
create index idx on maths_score (lang, timestamp, user, correct);
```

This is a covering index, starting with the columns in `WHERE`, continuing with the column in `GROUP BY` and ending with all other columns used in the query.